# What does this logcat line mean? I see it all the time but don't understand it

Tags: android, logcat

What does `trim memory level = TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE is scheduled for application: com.(some application name)` in logcat mean?

Comment: Don't you get desire answer? no response no update..

Comment: @user2549094 Do u find the solution from my answer???

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [**this link once**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) for detailed description. It states that

> Trim Memory is called when the operating system has determined that it is a good time for a process to trim unneeded memory from its process. This will happen for example when it goes in the background and there is not enough memory to keep as many background processes running as desired. You should never compare to exact values of the level, since new intermediate values may be added -- you will typically want to compare if the value is greater or equal to a level you are interested in.

and also this [**link**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html) which states that

> Level for onTrimMemory(int):The process is nearing the end of the background LRU list, and if more memory isn't found soon it will be killed.

Comment: @user2549094 do u find the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Following are words of [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html) site.

> Level for `onTrimMemory(int)`: the process is around the middle of the background LRU list; freeing memory can help the system keep other processes running later in the list for better overall performance.

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE)